# Cannot run a build on Monodevelop

Tags: linux, monodevelop

I've just installed Monodevelop IDE on my Lubuntu Linux as I've just migrated from Win10. After writing a quick Hello World program to test the IDE, I came up with the following text in the output console:

```
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.4 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=1.1.2&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.19.10-x64
```

Obviously I've got the latest .NET framework, but Monodevelop is requesting that I install an old version of it. I don't understand why as It's the latest Monodevelop version (as stated below)

```
=== MonoDevelop ===

Version 7.8.4 (build 2)
Installation UUID: 9a688c83-deba-4ab3-bbac-7cdb3e8b4050
    GTK+ 2.24.32 (Adwaita-dark theme)

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
    Mono 6.8.0.123 (tarball Tue May 12 15:11:57 UTC 2020) (64-bit)

=== NuGet ===

Version: 4.8.2.5835

=== .NET Core ===

Runtime: /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Version: 3.1.4
SDK: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Sdks
SDK Version: 3.1.300
MSBuild SDKs: /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 708040002
Git revision: 622db12503514afdb641c31615408bfe905a7312
Build date: 2019-07-17 17:02:07-04

=== Operating System ===

Linux
Linux 5.3.0-55-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:47:19 UTC 2020 x86_64
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: The "latest" MonoDevelop was 7.x which is quite old. For an abandoned project you really shouldn't ask for more. Switch to VSCode or Rider if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here, I solved the problem by modifying the file ".csproj":
Replace "netcoreapp1.1" with "netcoreapp3.1".

I did not find how to modify it directly on monodevelop